# Twitter Bootstrap: responsive navbar has gap on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a responsive navbar. It seems to work, but when the screen gets smaller, there appears a gap on the right side. See screen shot:

[image]

I haven't written any CSS. All of this is pure Bootstrap still.

**Update 1: jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/ - It's doing it on JSFiddle, too. So either I did something wrong (likely) or Twitter messed up (unlikely). `what to do?`

Comment: You'll need to include your markup.  Are you using the fluid classes?

Comment: Screen shot not enough? Navbars apparently does not use `.row` or `.row-fluid`, so I'm not sure what you mean. I'm trying to copy this from the docs.

Comment: try using `container-fluid` rather than `container` within the navbar

Comment: That's not what I see in the docs: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar. Will try.

Comment: All of the information about the responsive layouts are on the Scaffolding page and require extrapolation.

Comment: Didn't work. I'm struggling with the docs a bit.

Comment: You may need to set up a fiddle to reproduce the problem.  It should be easily isolated when viewed with browser tools. The container vs fluid actually wouldn't affect the background upon closer inspection.      Otherwise I'd suggest emptying out the navbar to see if that helps.

Comment: Matt, I posted a jsFiddle link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the markup that specifies that the elements should expand to fill the viewport.  Adding `body { width: 100%}` will take care of it, or optionally overriding the width of the `navbar` to be `auto`.

Twitter Bootstrap is intended to be scaffolding and components  rather than an out of the box solution, so this is likely one of those things that needs to be specified.  The `static` version of the navbar is likely written so that it can be easily used in containers other than the `body` and this happens to fall in the 20% of situations where it needs a nudge.

Comment: I added `body { width: 100%}` and it now works. However, how come the problem only presented itself when I reduce the width of the screen? Also, I tried `.container-fluid` per your comment, but I didn't see any difference in the behavior of the nav items; what was I supposed to see?

Comment: And on the subject of navbars, shouldn't a responsive navbar stack vertically when needed? Similar to the second navbar on this site http://bootswatch.com/slate/. I prefer that style over Bootstraps JS solution.

Comment: I hadn't checked the resize issue.  It may actually be a glitch in bootstrap after all.  Once the media query kicks in on screen resize the `body` is given a padding and the adjustments to the navbar aren't enough to counter it.  As far as vertical stacking you could do that yourself easily.  The navbar itself likely shouldn't do that since it's made to also hold elements aside from just nav links.

Comment: From what I've read in other forums it is important to note that anything that appear to be a "bug" may be consciously ignored by the bootstrap team since they're sticking to minimalism which is incredibly tough to keep once you start chasing down every minor issue.

Comment: I'm afraid to put in CSS to "fix" Bootstrap if the problem is actually something I did. I would rather rely on Bootstrap as much as possible. Thoughts?

Comment: Bootstrap is designed to allow you to hit the ground running, it's not supposed to be a panacea.  If you find yourself writing hacks then think twice (as always...or more times than that), but you shouldn't hesitate to write CSS which is clear and in-line with the intent of your site.

Comment: the solution has cause a problem. I have a secondary navigation. When the screen width is reduced, a horizontal scroll bar appears. Surely I'm not something right in Bootstrap? http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/2/

Comment: Then use:
`​body .navbar-static-top {
    width: auto;
}​`

These are dependent on how you're laying out your site.

Comment: I'm not defeating the purpose of Bootstrap with these CSS?

Comment: It's just supposed to help you with large grain pieces

Answer (score 0):

A few potential reasons come to mind, but as others have pointed out it's difficult to say without seeing code. I'll add, though, that I understand how tough it can be to share enough of your code for something like this without giving too much away. So here are some questions (and for this specific issue, you shouldn't use `.container-fluid` as previously suggested. that probably won't work anyway, and if it does it's only masking a problem that might compound):

- did you change any responsive styles? If so, did you change the width, padding, or margins on `.container`?
- Did you apply a width or margin to the `.navbar` itself somewhere in the responsive styles? This seems a likely cause to me.
- What about `<body>`, did you set padding on that?

Comment: I have NOT written any CSS. This is 100% Bootstrap.

Comment: could you try this maybe? when you preview the page in the browser, right click and save the page to a new folder somewhere. Then create a jsfiddle with the html and css inside that folder. you don't need to include the entire html page, just enough to reproduce the problem. Or if you would be more comfortable, feel free to look me up on github (same username) and contact me via email. I'm happy to try to figure it out for you.

Comment: Thanks. I've posted a jsFiddle link.

Comment: `container-fluid` is needed if you want the navbar _contents_ to react responsively, so depending on the design you're looking for you should use it, but that's not the issue being raised.

Comment: I used `.container` because that's what the docs has for this particular example. I'm still trying to get my head around Bootstrap. Was I wrong?

Comment: You can see the difference between the 2 by zooming out on the fiddle.  With `container-fluid` the navbar links will stretch to be aligned at the side of the screen as the screen goes very large.  With `container` they will stay aligned within a centered container that does not surpass a fixed width.  `container` is far more common, but can look awkward if your content is fully responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding (either) one of the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = no">
```